# How to fetch pages or articles using graphiql api in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, graphiql

I am trying to fetch the pages in Shopify GraphiQL App

I can fetch the store name using this schema

```
query{
  shop{
    name
  }
}
```

but **not able** to fetch the pages using following query

```
query{
      pages {
        name
        slug
        subtype
        icon
        keywords
        sections {
          htmlId
          label
          keywords
          html
          markdown
          showInNavigation
        }
    }
}
```

and getting error - Cannot query field "blogs" on type "RootQueryType"

Comment: These the documentation URL's to take look how the graphql works for [blogs](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/online-store/onlinestoreblog) and [articles](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/online-store/onlinestorearticle)